# Insert multiple queries into temp table mySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have the following stored procedure which I am migrating from SQL Server and I have done most of the changes to get this working on mySQL but I am having issues trying to insert multiple query results into the temp table:

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Routine DDL
-- Note: comments before and after the routine body will not be stored by the server
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`Test`@`%` PROCEDURE `ListDBATree`()
BEGIN

DECLARE seq int(10);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE if not exists DBA_TREE(
ID VARCHAR(10),
NAME VARCHAR(50),
PARENT VARCHAR(30),
VALUE VARCHAR(30),
TYPE varchar(30)
);


insert into DBA_TREE (NAME,VALUE,PARENT,TYPE )
select VIEWNAME, SEQUENCE, null, 'None' from SD_TABLES where HIDDEN = 0;
insert into DBA_TREE (NAME,VALUE,PARENT, TYPE)
select a.DISPLAY_NAME, a.SEQUENCE, (select ID from DBA_TREE where VALUE = a.SEQ_TABLE), a.TYPE from SD_FIELDS a join SD_TABLES b on a.SEQ_TABLE = b.SEQUENCE WHERE b.HIDDEN = 0 and a.ISVIRTUAL = 0;
insert into DBA_TREE (NAME,VALUE,PARENT, TYPE)
select a.DISPLAY_NAME, a.SEQUENCE, (select ID from DBA_TREE where VALUE = a.SEQ_PARENT), a.TYPE from SD_FIELDS a join SD_TABLES b on a.SEQ_TABLE = b.SEQUENCE WHERE b.HIDDEN = 0 and a.ISVIRTUAL = 1;

select * from DBA_TREE;

END
```

This is the error:

```
Error Code: 1137. Can't reopen table: 'DBA_TREE'
```

Comment: This is a known limitation of temp tables in MySQL. Cf. http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=10327

Comment: Yes I did find that before I posted on here but wasn't sure if it was the same issue. I will have to think of another solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Bill mentioned this is a known bug and my earlier answer of doing a `union` will not work as well cause the bug says a temp table can't be referenced more than once. For example you can't do even like below, which will cause the same error cause referring the table more than once.

```
select * from DBA_TREE dt1,DBA_TREE dt2 on dt1.id = dt2.id
```

My earlier answer of doing a `union` will not work as well cause you are essentially referring the table more than once (see below)

```
insert into DBA_TREE (NAME,VALUE,PARENT,TYPE )
select VIEWNAME, SEQUENCE, null, 'None' from SD_TABLES where HIDDEN = 0;
union
select a.DISPLAY_NAME, a.SEQUENCE, (select ID from DBA_TREE where VALUE = 
.....                                               -- Here Again
```

I know it's a real awkward bug and if you go through the bug profile fully, you will see that many people have faced tough situation for this and request to provide fix but none have been introduced till date (not even a workaround).

So, in this situation your best bet would be to work with a normal table rather than a temp table.

- create the table
- Use it
- Drop it

  Since you are doing all inside a stored proc, you can do like

> ```
> CREATE TABLE if not exists DBA_TREE(
> ID VARCHAR(10),
> NAME VARCHAR(50),
> PARENT VARCHAR(30),
> VALUE VARCHAR(30),
> TYPE varchar(30)
> );
> ```

```
insert into DBA_TREE (NAME,VALUE,PARENT,TYPE )
select VIEWNAME, SEQUENCE, null, 'None' from SD_TABLES where HIDDEN = 0;
insert into DBA_TREE (NAME,VALUE,PARENT, TYPE)
select a.DISPLAY_NAME, a.SEQUENCE, (select ID from DBA_TREE where VALUE = 
a.SEQ_TABLE), a.TYPE from SD_FIELDS a join SD_TABLES b on a.SEQ_TABLE = 
b.SEQUENCE WHERE b.HIDDEN = 0 and a.ISVIRTUAL = 0;
insert into DBA_TREE (NAME,VALUE,PARENT, TYPE)
select a.DISPLAY_NAME, a.SEQUENCE, (select ID from DBA_TREE where VALUE = 
a.SEQ_PARENT), a.TYPE from SD_FIELDS a join SD_TABLES b on a.SEQ_TABLE = 
b.SEQUENCE WHERE b.HIDDEN = 0 and a.ISVIRTUAL = 1;


select * from DBA_TREE;
```

Then before your stored procedure hit the `END` mark, drop the table

```
drop table DBA_TREE;
```

Comment: The limitation on opening temp tables multiple times in a query applies to UNION too, according to a comment in the bug report I referenced above.

Comment: @BillKarwin, that's correct. whole point here is can't refer the table more than once. `Union` would have worked proper if OP haven't refereed the temp table in his select as well. I have edited the answer accordingly.